# Convert string element to integer C++

Tags: c++, string, integer

i have a string of numbers, and i want to multiply these numbers

```
string myS = "731671765313";
int product = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<myS.length(); i++)
        product *= myS[i];
```

How to convert the string element to int because the result is totally wrong.
I tried casting it to **int** but in vain.

Comment: You can't just randomly "cast" an ASCII character to an integer and expect to get a number out of it! What you do think `(int)'a'` does? ;)

Comment: do you want to multiply all digits? then character to int conversion is `(myS[i]-'0')`, otherwise this is a duplicate and you should use `std::stoi`

Comment: I tried `atoi(myS[i])` and `stoi(myS[i])` ...... error

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, The question *really* seems to be about multiplying the digits in the string, not converting the string. The loop in the code makes this evident.

Comment: @chris I agree. Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `std::accumulate` (because you're accumulating a product of elements, so it makes the intent clear) and recall that `'0'` is not 0, but that the digit characters are contiguous. For example, in ASCII, `'0'` is 48, `'1'` is 49, etc. Therefore, subtracting `'0'` will convert that character (if it's a digit) to the appropriate numerical value.

```
int product = std::accumulate(std::begin(s), std::end(s), 1, 
    [](int total, char c) {return total * (c - '0');}
);
```

If you can't use C++11, it's easily replaced:

```
int multiplyCharacterDigit(int total, char c) {
    return total * (c - '0');
}

...

int product = std::accumulate(s.begin(), s.end(), 1, multiplyCharacterDigit);
```

If neither of those are an option, what you had is almost there:

```
int product = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<myS.length(); i++)
        product *= (myS[i] - '0');
```

Comment: your solution requires a C++11-compliant implementation of the language, you should specify that.

Comment: @user2485710, As far as I'm aware, the C++ tag is C++11 by default, but I have made accommodations.

Comment: @Misaki, Is there a specific problem with either of the others besides one requiring C++11, or is it just that the last one is best suited to you? I didn't exactly test the second one, so if there's something wrong, I'd be glad to fix it.

Comment: "If you can't use C++", you forgot _11_ ; by the way, like you, I wish that C++11 was more popular, but older C++ standards are still more popular than C++11.

Comment: @chris i think the last one is simpler than the others, no need to make it complicated. Besides i want to multiply certain elements from the string.

Comment: @user2485710, Thanks for that. And I know what you mean, but it is gaining popularity, and it'll soon be a standard behind :)

Comment: @Misaki, The others are more idiomatic is all. Someone reading it can instantly tell there's some accumulation going on. It's not too frequent when beginning, but handwritten loops are often discouraged.